# n and R(n) both divisible by 3^K

Tags: number-theory

For natural numbers n,let R(n) be the reversal of n, and  n and R(n) are two DISTINCT natural numbers.  18 and its reversal 81 are both divisible by 9. My question is: Do there always exist a number n such that both n and R(n) are divisible by 3^K ? (it will be very nice if you also give smallest solutions for each K)

Comment: It might help to notice that in the representation of powers of $3$, each digit repeats periodically as a function of the exponent. Let $Dm_n=\lfloor\frac{3^n}{10^m}\rfloor\bmod{10}$ denote the $m$th digit of $3^n$. Then the period of the sequence $Dm$ is equal to $4\cdot5^m$.

Comment: @barakmanos so your answer is ...

Comment: It's just an observation, not an answer (but I doubt that there **is** such number).

Comment: @barakmanos okay, thanks for your comments

Comment: For example, the sequence which stands for the $1$st digit is $D_{0}=1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,\dots$, and its period is $4$.

Comment: What about both n and R(n) divisible by 27 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
1998=27\times 74,\quad 8991=27\times 333
$$

$$
1999999998=3^4\times24691358,\quad 8999999991=3^4\times111111111
$$

Looks like a pattern.
$$
3^k\mid2\,(10^{3^k}-1),\quad 3^k\mid9\,(10^{3^k}-1).
$$